# Change the color of a row based on string data in a cell using VB in excel

Tags: string, vba, colors, row, excel-2007

I have an excel spreadsheet where I would like to highlight all the rows where the string "05 Paint" appears in cells in column A.  I found this code that changes the color of the cell containing the string "05 Paint" but can't figure out how to highlight the whole row:

```
Sub Highlight()
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("A2:A250")
For Each cell In rng
   Select Case cell.Value
       Case "05 Paint"
       cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
   End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Ideally I would like the row to be highlighted from column A to column I.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Cell.Resize(1, 9).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

So you know which row to be highlighted. That makes it none-dynamic.

You can try "conditional formatting" for that row. Plus going through each cell could be as nearly costly as my suggestion. 
You can try and compare the best performance gain solutiin for your need.

Answer (score 0):

Where "entire row" has been defined a ColumnsA:I, the search string is `05 Paint` (being either all of or part of the cell content) and the search is case insensitive then:

Record Macro:

select ColumnsA:I, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule...

*Use a formula to determine which cells to format*
**Format values where this formula is true:**

```
=SEARCH("05 Paint",$A1)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting, OK, OK.

Stop recording.